# NSPredicate: joining on an object or an object-id

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have a coredata datamodel with a 1:n relationship

```
Entity Item
Tag *tag;
....

Entity Tag
NSString *name;
```

I want to fetch Items, witch have a relationship to a Tag.
The following works:

```
Tag *selectedTag = .....
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Item"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tag.name =  %@", selectedTag.name];
```

The Problem is, there coud be more than one tags with the same name.
These Items should not be fetched.

How can I directly compare directly the object (selectedTag) or at least a compare to an id.

Both:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tag == %@", selectedTag];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"[tag objectID] == %@", [selectedTag objectID] ];
```

do not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want the inverse relationship of the tag.

If the Foo has a to-one relationship to Tag called `tagMember`, the inverse of which is Tag's to-many relationship to Foo called `fooMembers`, then to get a set of all foos whose `tagMember` is the selected tag, you would do this:

```
NSSet *setOfFoos = selectedTag.fooMembers;
```

Or, if you haven't set up a subclass for Tag and therefore can't use dot syntax, you would do this:

```
NSSet *setOfFoos = [selectedTag valueForKey:@"fooMembers"];
```

(In other words, since you already have the item which is related to the objects you are looking for, you can get those objects directly from that item, rather than running a fetch.)

Comment: Thanks, but how looks the NSPredicate for this "query"? I don´t want to fetch the Tag and than navigate the relationship. Is there no other way?

Comment: to clarify: I want to use a NSFetchedResultsController in a TableView. Isn´t that better for a large number of Items, than having the whole set in memory?

Comment: You'll initialize your fetchedResultsController with a fetchRequest in order to populate the table before you display it. It's unlikely that you'll want to request specific object IDs in that fetch. If you want to populate the table with only a few tags at a time, you could use predicates something like your `tag.name == %@`. See FRC class ref re "Modifying the Fetch Request." Once the table is up and running and the user selects a tag, you can get the selected tag from the table delegate methods. You won't need another fetch at that point.

Comment: @mica whether you use an FRC makes no difference about having the whole set in memory. Any managed object can be faulted back to the persistent store by the object's context if the memory limit is reached. this is what makes it a "managed" object. the FRC just provides the convenience of listening for inserts, changes, or deletes in a particular context

Answer (score 0):

For a given entity with a relationship to a parent, you can use a predicate that relies on the child entity itself.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tag == %@", selectedTag];
```

Apply this predicate to your NSFetchRequest for the parent entity. For a 1:n relationship you should get a result set containing 0 or 1 parent entities.